# Provide an Instance as its interface in Koin

Tags: kotlin, koin

Lets say I have two interfaces like:

```
interface LetterClassifier
interface NumberClassifier
```

Then these interfaces would be applied to this class:

```
class Classifier() : LetterClassifier, NumberClassifier
```

Now, I want to provide these instances only as `LetterClassifier` and `NumberClassifier` and not as `Classifier` in `Koin`.

The way I think of doing this is by doing:

```
module {
    val classifier = Classifier()

    single<NumberClassifier> { classifier }
    single<LetterClassifier> { classifier }
}
```

But I don't think this is the right way. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could **bind** types to your definition like it is described on [official article](https://medium.com/koin-developers/ready-for-koin-2-0-2722ab59cac3#659b):

```
single { Classifier() } binds arrayOf(LetterClassifier::class, NumberClassifier::class)
```

If you want to exclude `Classifier` type at all you could do something like:

```
single<LetterClassifier> { Classifier() } bind NumberClassifier::class
```

Answer (score 6):

The way you're doing it is in fact the right way! Here's another example [from the Koin docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/quick-references/modules-definitions/), doing the same thing:

```
class DataRepository()
interface Presenter
class MyPresenter(val repository : Repository) : Presenter

val myModule = module {
    // Define a singleton for type  DataRepository
    single { DataRepository() }

    // Define a factory (create a new instance each time) for type Presenter (infered parameter in <>) 
    // Resolve constructor dependency with get()
    factory<Presenter> { MyPresenter(get()) }
}
```

One small thing to note when doing this: your approach immediately creates an instance at the time the module declaration is being processed, while placing the constructor calls in the `single` lambdas would create instances when needed:

```
single<NumberClassifier> { Classifier() }
single<LetterClassifier> { Classifier() }
```

Although this *would* create a separate single instance for both of the interfaces.

Comment: But I the same Instance. It is possible to do so without immediately creating the instance? Or should I simply make the instantiation lazy so it would create it immediately?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function or a Singleton to provide instance,

```
single<NumberClassifier> { Singleton.createClassifier() }
single<LetterClassifier> { Singleton.createClassifier() }
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea. You'll be defining 3 singleton for just 1 instance. The selected answer is the correct answer.