# How to pass an interface as parameter in koin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I'm so beginner in koin.

I have a method that named "MesheRepoImpl" that get an interface as parameter.

I know that I can't pass an interface to a method in Koin, so I created a class and extends that from the interface then I added that class in koin module, so I use the class as parameter for MesheRepoImpl.

But android studio gives me this error:

Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.app.meshe.data.repo.MesheRepo'. Check your definitions!

This is my Di module:

```
val mesheModule =
    module {
        single { getInstance(androidContext()) }
        single { MesheLocalDataSource() } //*
        single { MesheRepoImpl(get()) } //**
        factory { TaskViewModelFactory(get()) }
        viewModel { TaskViewModel(get()) }
        viewModel { RewardViewModel(get()) }
        viewModel {MainViewModel()}
    }
```

The 1 star line is my class that extends from the interface and the 2 stars line is the class that get interface as parameter.

How can I pass the interface as parameter, if I can't use a class?

Comment: check this answer
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816557/provide-an-instance-as-its-interface-in-koin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's still no answer, I'd advise you to consider going with

```
interface MesheRepo
class MeshoRepoImpl(): MeshoRepo
```

over your

```
interface MesheRepo
class MeshoRepoImpl(val IRepo: MeshoRepo)
```

So, just implement `MeshoRepo` over passing it as an argument to `MeshoRepoImpl`.

Trying to answer directly your question, you are able to define interfaces in Koin module and pass them, but you have to provide their implementations, as well:

```
val mesheModule = module {
  single<MeshoRepo> { MeshoRepoImpl() }
  single { MeshoRepoImpl(get()) } // <-- it's like a deadlock, so I still do not see any sense to pass an interface over implementing it
}
```

And, please, do not forget that an interface is not an object.

Comment: In this case I have to pass an interface as parameter for MesheRepoImpl but you didn't do that in this line:   single<MeshoRepo> { MeshoRepoImpl() }. So it has an Error. How can I fix that?

Comment: @HoomanHooshyar my below code intentionally causes an error, since I wanted to show that what you want is kind of clumsy. The main point is: you can pass an interface as a parameter, but you must provide its implementation first. `single<MeshoRepo> { MeshoRepoImpl() }` provides an implementation for the `MeshoRepo` interface. What error does that line cause? An error should be thrown by the next line, since that is a kind of deadlock.

Comment: I'm so confuse. I just want to use Room in my project with Koin :( I couldn't find a good tutorial. I'm so beginner in Koin. I can't understand your solution by this way